# Peer Dependency error while deploying to Vercel

Tags: deployment, next.js, dependencies, vercel

I am trying to deploy my NextJS application onto Vercel but each time at the deploy stage, I am met with these errors and the deployment will fail:

```
Previous build cache not available
Cloning completed: 426.52ms
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 28.6.0
Installing dependencies...
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-typed@1.2.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from next@13.0.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/next
npm ERR!     next@"13.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   3 more (react-dom, react-icons, styled-jsx)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.3.0" from react-typed@1.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-typed
npm ERR!   react-typed@"^1.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.3.0" from react-typed@1.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-typed
npm ERR!     react-typed@"^1.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /vercel/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2022-12-02T16_42_09_037Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

I have tried running `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` and tried redeploying onto Vercel, but the same issue persists. When I run this application on my localhost:3000 using `npm run dev`, the application renders fine. Anyone knows what I can do?

I have tried

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

and also pushing these changes onto my GitHub repository. When redeploying, the same issue still shows. I run

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

again, but this time, there are no more changes to be made.

Answer (score 1):

you can override the installing command used by Vercel CLI, either by:

1. Going to Vercel Dashboard ->  -> Settings -> General -> Scroll to **Build & Development Settings** and put `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` in Install Command
2. Creating `vercel.json` file in the root directory of your project that should contain:

```json
// vercel.json
{
  "installCommand": "npm install --legacy-peer-deps"
}
```

after that push and wait for deployment, it should go through this time

But I recommend looking for the cause of this issue. It seems like some dependency you're using is depending on `react-typed`, and the latter is not maintained anymore. It's better to seek an alternative

Comment: The question is why local installation is successful and on Vercel it crashes. I have a similar issue sometimes where when I install locally with `npm i` or `npm ci` it goes successfully without any issues but when installing on vercel's build step it crashes on perr dependencies conflict. I assume vercel is using some more stricter form of npm install but I can't understand what it is and where I can read about it to get more info and actually search for a root cause.